# Why is my Plot3D not showing a gap?

Tags: plotting

I used Mathematica to find the `ArgMax` of a function and plot the output. The results I am getting is not consistent with existing results. Here is what I did;

```
w[x_, j_, h_] := 1/2 j x^2 + h x - ((1 - x)/2*Log[(1 - x)/2] + (1 + x)/2*Log[(1 + x)/2])
d[j_, h_] = ArgMax[{w[x, j, h], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
Plot3D[d[j, h], {j, 0, 2}, {h, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

On the otherhand this is supposed to be the result
[image]

So with my Mathematica code, the jump that forms a **U** shape is missing and it has been the case for most of the plots I'm generating. Is there a way this can be corrected in Mathematica or executed in python, if yes how will that be done. Any suggestions and ideas are welcome. Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Can you supply the code used (assuming in Python) used to generate the 2nd plot?  Additionally, it looks like the axis in the Mathematica plot reverses the J axis of the second plot.  Running the J axis the same will get you closer.  The missing "U" shape may get addressed with a finer mesh or some constraints on the mesh.  Just some initial thoughts.

Comment: add the option `ExclusionsStyle -> None`?

Comment: @kglr that doesn't make a difference unfortunately. Mathematica should be able to handle a branch cut without needing to add this. For example `Plot3D[Im[ArcSin[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` has cuts and doesn't need any exclusions options.

Comment: @Jagra I do not really know if it was generated by python, but in principle or if you study the function there is a jump at 1 for the J axis. What was done to the 2nd plot was to find the ArgMax of  "w" over "x" and plot the result. I tried this in Matlab but it does not work at all and my feeling is having a different software to do the same work could clear out the dust.

Comment: I then suggest that you add the function you want to implement in Mathematica, so that everyone can compare, what you intend to do with your current implementation.  We'll get you where you want to go, just work with us.

Comment: @Jagra What i want to do is to maximize `w[x_, j_, h_] := 1/2 j x^2 + h x - ((1 - x)/2*Log[(1 - x)/2] + (1 + x)/2*Log[(1 + x)/2])` over only `-1 <= x <= 1` and generate a 3D surface of the maximum for `0 <= j <= 2` and `-1 <= h <= 1`.

Comment: @kglr I have tried the ExclusionsStyle but still not getting the right output.

Comment: @Jagra Do you know how I can make a finer mesh or discretize the intervals to get a finer mesh? I have tried using  `x == N@Subdivide[-1, 1, 1000]` but I get the response that `ArgMax`  `....should be either Reals or Integers`.

Answer (score 4):

My actual best workaround using `Exclusions`:

```
Show[{
Plot3D[d[j, h], {j, 0, 1 }, {h, -1, 1} ], 
Plot3D[d[j, h], {j, 1, 2}, {h, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> {h == 0  }]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Exclusions can take a condition (note the extra braces): `Plot3D[d[j, h], {j, 0, 2}, {h, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> {{h == 0, j > 1}}]`.  The hard trick is to compute the exclusions automatically.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann @Micheal E2 I appreciate your comments. Looking at the case I have, I knew the jump is at j = 1 but how is it that I am unable to get the right thing without the `Exclusions` command. Now, assuming I am unaware of such behaviour of the function, how will I tell mathematica to do the right thing.

Comment: @BDG That's what I meant by "The hard trick is to compute the exclusions automatically."

Comment: @MichaelE2 Simple "hard trick" `Method->"Discontinuity"`  doesn't work , unfortunately

Comment: @BDG A condition for the discontinuity is that the global maximum occurs at multiple locations $x$.  Then a small perturbation of the parameters will cause the max to be in a neighborhood of just one of the locations and potentially result in a discontinuity. If you can compute the locus for $(j,h)$ for which the max occurs a multiple locations, then you have a way to compute the locus to give to `Exclusions`. I may have a way to numerically approximate the locus, but I need to test its feasibility when I get to a computer.

Comment: @Michael E2 It will be nice to see how to do the approximation of the locus.

Comment: @BDG It's not working well. The basic idea was to discretely approximate the Jacobian and exclude extremely large norms. At discontinuities the norm would theoretically go to infinity as the step size approaches zero. Theoretically, such an approach would exclude discontinuities and loci with vertical tangent planes. It works better using `RegionFunction` than `Exclusions` on. But I could never run it on your example. There's some noise from `ArgMax`; but on the full example, it never finished, and the longest I let it run was about an hour. And it used all four cores in parallel.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The `ArgMax` has some noise that I am unable to resolve. I don't know if there is another way of finding the `ArgMax`.